# For the CLI wallet, how can I teach myself all that it can do?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod-commands, linux

Monero has motivated me to get interested in Linux.  I'm relatively inexperienced with Linux.  To those more experienced, this question may seem like a silly one.  I expect I'm not the only Linux n00b (well, CLI n00b), so I hope this question helps many people.

I've managed to install Monero on Ubuntu a few times now.  Once I get it installed, I only know that `./monerod` (formerly `./bitmonerod`) will make the daemon run.  Once it's running, I can type --`help` for a list of commands.  Similarly, I can get `monero-wallet-cli` (formerly, `simplewallet`) running, and I can run --`help` there too for its commands.  My knowledge pretty much ends there.  But I know there is much more that those two programs can do.

For example, I've asked on IRC chat whether I can run a node on one computer that I always keep on, and then run the wallet from another computer that only refreshes itself from my personal node.  The IRC fellow mentioned adding commands like `--rpc-bind-ip` and `--daemon-host`.  Are those commands listed somewhere?  Where do I find the full list?

I hope a question so basic will help lots of people in my shoes that want to get their hands dirty, but are missing some [probably pretty elementary] tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to type help BEFORE running the software, like ./monerod --help

Answer (score 6):

Utilise the "flag" --help to see additional options regarding the software. i.e './monerod --help'

Answer (score 2):

*Using* monero is teaching me....find a use case for it or some reason to justify spending the fee, and do a little experimenting with it. Having used monero a handful of times, i've learned a bit about payment ID's. Did you know that to use shapeshift for example, you have to use a payment ID? When I learned that, it seems like payment ID's will be necessary often with Monero because of the inherant anonymity features.